# Check if a Winforms BackgroundWorker is active upon opening a form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I currently have a `Main` form that contains a `SplitPanel` object. In the left panel, I have several buttons that when clicked, will open a specific form in the right panel.

One of these forms, `Reports`, has a `BackgroundWorker` (`bgLaborForecast`) that does a lot of database table maintenance and building of data tables in the database for reporting purposes.  While this `BackgroundWorker` is running, I can navigate to any other form simply by clicking the appropriate button in the left panel of the `Main` form.  When the `BackGroundWorker` is done, it displays a `MessageBox`, no matter where I am in the application.

What I am trying to accomplish is to check if the `BackgroundWorker` is running when I load the `Reports` form.  I tried

```
if (bgLaborForecast.IsBusy) { 
    MessageBox.Show("Busy...");
}
```

But when I enter the form, the `.IsBusy` status is always false.

How can I check for the process being active when I load the form?

Comment: do you have BackgroundWorker in the `Main form` and you wanted to open new form if the BackgroundWorker is not busy?

Comment: No, the BackgroundWorker is in the form that I am opening.  Its possible the form gets opened, the background process gets kicked off, and then the form is closed and another is opened.  I want to check if the process is running if I reopen the form that has the BackgroundWorker on it.

Comment: Not clear enought what you trying to do. In `MainForm` you got `Buttons`, `onClick` create `NewForm` and start in `NewForm` `BgWorker`, and when click on another `Button` on `MainForm` you want stop `BgWorker` on `NewForm` close `NewForm`, and then create `NewForm2` and start `BgWorker` in `NewForm2`? Is that correct?

Comment: No.  In Main form, click button1 that opens Form1.  Form1 has a bgworker that I start with Buttonbgstart  on form1.  Then in main form, I click button2 that opens form2.  Then a bit later, I click button1 again from the main form to reopen form1, I need to check if the bgworker is still running

Comment: @KeithClark - When you say you **reopen** `Form1` do you mean you **activate** the already created `Form1` (that you started the background process on) or are your **creating** a new `Form1` and showing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do interface

```
public interface IState
{
    bool BgWorkerIsWorking { get; set; }
}
```

then implement it in Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IState
...
private bool _working;
public bool BgWorkerIsWorking
{
    get { return _working; }
    set { _working = value; }
}
```

In MainForm declare variable to keep form

```
Form firstForm;
```

And in button this

```
if (first == null)// If form wasn't created
{
    first = new Form2();// Create form and show
    first.Show();
}
else// If form was created
{
    var check = first as IState;// Use form as our interface
    if (check.BgWorkerIsWorking)// And check state
    {
        // Here you do something.
    }
}
```

And at last in Form1 in BgWorker events you do this

```
private void Bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _working = true;
    // Here is your code
}
private void Bg_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _working = false;
}
```

Ofcourse your worker initialization must be this

```
using (BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker())
{
    bg.DoWork += Bg_DoWork;
    bg.RunWorkerCompleted += Bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

And just in case, worker start work after

```
bg.RunWorkerAsync();
```

P.S. 
This steps must be repeated for each form you create. declare secondForm, thirdForm and so on.
P.P.S. 
You can design more complicated algorithm, store created forms in array, add extra fields in interface and so on. This example show basic principle :)

Comment: I think I understand the principal here.  I am going to try out some code and see if it fits what I am looking for. Thanks.